# Bottom Navigation Bar gets messed up after clearing flag translucent status flag

Tags: android, bottomnavigationview

if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {

```
        window = getActivity().getWindow();

        window.clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS|
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_NAVIGATION);


        window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);

        //window.setStatusBarColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.profile_header));

        window.setStatusBarColor(Color.parseColor("#f9fafc"));

    }
```

[check out screen shot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xwxck.png)

Comment: window.getDecorView().requestApplyInsets();  worked after clearing Transcluent flag.